# Flutter: Persisting Page States

Tags: flutter

Even after reading [this](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@tensor/persisting-user-interface-state-and-building-bottom-navigation-bars-in-dart-s-flutter-framework) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195114/flutter-persistent-state-between-pages), I still can't seem to wrap my head around storing page states in Flutter.

I've built a sample app, which has a main page called `MyHomePage` and a second page called `SecondPage`. `MyHomePage` has a floating action button, which displays `SecondPage` via `Navigator.push(...)`. The second page contains a text field with an assigned controller. I would like to preserve the text field's text after I close and reopen `SecondPage`.

I've tried all sorts of combinations with setting buckets, page states and keys (inspired by the links above), but I couldn't make it work.

Also I'd like to store the whole page state automatically - without the need to write/retrieve every single value manually (in case I have a lot of text fields on the page).

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

PageStorageKey mykey = new PageStorageKey("testkey");

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final PageStorageBucket _bucket = new PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PageStorage(
        bucket: _bucket,
        child: MyHomePage(),
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("State demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _openSecondPage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  _openSecondPage() {
    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()));
  }

}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  final _aController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _aController,
          key: mykey,
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on Ajay's answer, I was able to greatly simplify the working code. Turns out that in order to persist widget states manually, all you need is an instance of `PageStorageBucket` in combination with `ValueKey` instances.

Here are the modifications I did to Ajay's code:

- Removed the after_layout plugin (`initState` method is sufficient).
- Removed the global `PageStorageKey` instance (replaced it with a local `ValueKey` instance in the page that needs to use it).
- Removed global instance of `PageStorageBucket` and replaced it with a final instance in `MyApp`, which is passed to the pages that need it via constructor attributes.

  - Removed `PageStorage` from the component tree.

Here is the resulting code (simplest working form):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(bucket: bucket,),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  final PageStorageBucket bucket;

  const MyHomePage({Key key, this.bucket}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("State demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _openSecondPage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  _openSecondPage() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage(bucket: widget.bucket,)));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final PageStorageBucket bucket;

  const SecondPage({Key key, this.bucket}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  static const KEY_A = ValueKey("secondPage.A");

  final _aController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _aController.addListener(_updateValue);

    String value = widget.bucket.readState(context, identifier: KEY_A) ?? "";
    _aController.text = value;
  }

  _updateValue() {
    widget.bucket.writeState(context, _aController.text, identifier: KEY_A);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _aController,
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to read and write the state as well.

[image: demo]

Check out the below code.

Note: I have used [after_layout](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout) to initialize the text controller.

```
import 'package:after_layout/after_layout.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

PageStorageKey mykey = new PageStorageKey("testkey");
final PageStorageBucket _bucket = new PageStorageBucket();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: PageStorage(
          bucket: _bucket,
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ));
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("State demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _openSecondPage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  _openSecondPage() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>
    with AfterLayoutMixin<SecondPage> {
  final _aController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _aController.addListener(_updateValue);
  }

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    String value =
        _bucket.readState(context, identifier: ValueKey(mykey)) ?? "";
    print(value);
    _aController.text = value;
  }

  _updateValue() {
    _bucket.writeState(context, _aController.text, identifier: ValueKey(mykey));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          controller: _aController,
          key: mykey,
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful, thanks. But when you have a lot of components on a page, doing this for every single component is cumbersome. According to this article: [https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@tensor/persisting-user-interface-state-and-building-bottom-navigation-bars-in-dart-s-flutter-framework], you should be able to store the whole page using a `PageStorageKey`. I'd really love if I could to make that work.